# In window worker service dot net core when i publish than getting database error otherwise it works?

Tags: c#, .net-core

**When I test on debug mode database run succesfully but when i publish the app then i am getting error.**
**Below Error I am getting -**

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'MyDatabase'. [CLIENT: ]
> Category: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection EventId: 20004

> An error occurred using the connection to database 'MyDatabase' on server 'DESKTOP-sandeep\SQLEXPRESS'.

> Category: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.QueryEventId: 10100
> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'DemoLoggerWS.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.
> System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure' to the 'UseSqlServer' call.
> ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed.
> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.

**Program.cs file code -**

```
using DemoLoggerWS;
using DemoLoggerWS.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Serilog;

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.File(@"D:\Sunil\SampleProjects\PublishWS\DemoLoggerV3\log.txt").CreateLogger();
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService(options =>
    {
        options.ServiceName = "Demo Logger Test";
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(logging => 
    { 
        logging.AddSerilog(); 
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer("Server=DESKTOP-4NUBQP8\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;") 
        );
        
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

**Worker.cs file code**

```
namespace DemoLoggerWS
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IServiceScopeFactory factory)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _db = factory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            { 
                // Below code getting data from database
                var resul = _db.Category.ToList();

                _logger.LogWarning("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), stoppingToken);
            }
        } 

    }
}
```

**AppSetting.json file Code --**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-Sandeep\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```

Comment: One thing to note is that the EF DbContext is supposed to be short lived object. The way you are injecting it into the worker class will make it's lifetime as long as the Worker class, which I presume is a long one, which is not a good practice.

Comment: @user2884940: did changing the DB name solved the issue?

Comment: @Stefan no it was just typing mistake.
Also i  tried first option which you mention "enable SQL Server login" . Still i am getting same error

Comment: That is not possible. If you tried the first option the username must have changed and hence you'll get a different error. Please show the full new error as well.

Comment: Also please show sql server login is enabled and the created user has access to the targeted database.

Comment: Also: please double check the published version of the connection string

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the provided database exists at the targeted machine;

by specifying `Trusted_Connection=True` in your connection string, you're saying that the user running the application will try to log in into the database.

Looking at the error, your service is running under user:

```
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
```

This user apparently has no access to the database. To resolve this, you have 3 options, the easiest:

- enable SQL Server login and specify those credentials explicitly in your connection string

And more complicated ones:

- have the service run under a specific account which has access.
- give the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` user rights to access the database (not recommended)

It's easiest to go for the first, it is described below.

#### enable SQL Server login

Most common approach for trusted systems is to enable SQL login or create a specific SQL user. It is easy and flexible. [Here's a quick guide](https://www.mydatahack.com/how-to-enable-user-login-with-sql-server-express/).

Your connection string should than include the login: e.g.:

```
"Server=DESKTOP-4NUBQP8\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase;User Id=userid;Password=password;"
```

#### have the service run under a specific account which has access

Basically this mean you need to reconfigure the service to run under a dedicated user account on the OS. This is a clean way, but will cause some with some user management overhead.

Tutorials can be found online.

#### give the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` user rights to access the database

It will work, but you should avoid this because all services running under this account will have access to your data.